# How to use a loop to generate a list using previous output as input?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a code that generates a weekly change in price for n weeks using a price input, but I'm seeing that the recursion uses the initial input for all weeks. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

input

```
def price():
    discount = 0.88
    price = 0
    price = float(input('Enter price:\n'))
    for i in range(6):
        newPrice = round((price * discount), 2)
        print('Week',i+1,'price is:','$',newPrice)
```

output

```
Enter price: 10
Week 1 price is: $ 8.8
Week 2 price is: $ 8.8
Week 3 price is: $ 8.8
Week 4 price is: $ 8.8
Week 5 price is: $ 8.8
Week 6 price is: $ 8.8
```

desired output

```
Enter price: 10
Week 1 price is: $ 8.8
Week 2 price is: $ 7.74
Week 3 price is: $ 6.81
Week 4 price is: $ 5.99
Week 5 price is: $ 5.27
Week 6 price is: $ 4.64
```

Comment: There's no recursion in your code, just an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Please see any tutorial on loan amortization to learn how to update status variables.

Comment: You need to assign the result of the computation to `price`, not `newPrice` so that the changes will accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

During your for loop `price` is never updated, thus `newPrice` keeps the same value the whole time. Also, there's no recursion taking place

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by storing the substituting your initial `price` value to the `newPrice` value. So `newPrice` is redundant and we can remove it.
Like this:

```py
def price():
    discount = 0.88
    price = 0
    price = float(input('Enter price:\n'))
    for i in range(6):
        price = round((price * discount), 2)
        print('Week',i+1,'price is:','$', price)
```

Also see that in python we usually use [snake case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

So it would be better to use `new_price`.

Ans for money calculation it's common to use [`decimal` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Thanks! That was embarrassingly easy. Regarding snake case, I don't know why my lecturer insists on this particular convention, my other classes recommend using an underscore as opposed to capitalization.